# How can I parse modis MOD13Q1 quality layers in R?

Tags: r, remote-sensing, modis, data-quality, cloud-cover

I'd like to parse MOD13Q1 VI quality layers in R.  My original code must have been incorrect, because it gave lots of "deep ocean" flags in the middle of Brazil.  After the changes suggested by Mikkel, that's no longer the case.  However I do see some VI usefulness values that don't appear in the documentation.  I'm not sure whether that's a problem or whether the documentation is incomplete -- will explain further below.  Here's my code, after the change suggested by Mikkel:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

## See http://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODLAND_grid.html: h11v09 should be entirely non-ocean
filename <- "MOD13Q1.A2013001.h11v09.005.2013018041108.250m_16_days_VI_Quality.tif"
qual <- raster(file.path("data", "modis", filename))
range(qual[])  # 2061 to 65535; only bits 0-15 have meaning and sum(2^(0:15)) = 65535

first_k_bits <- function(int, k=16, reverse=T) {
    ## https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/modis_products_table/mod13q1 TABLE 2:
    ## MOD13Q1 VI Quality: "Bit 0 is the least significant (read bit words right to left)"
    integer_vector <- as.integer(intToBits(int))[1:k]
    if(reverse) integer_vector <- rev(integer_vector)
    return(paste(as.character(integer_vector), collapse=""))
}
df <- data.frame(bits=sapply(qual[], function(x) first_k_bits(x, k=16, reverse=T)))
df$bits[qual[] == 65535] <- NA  # sum(2^(0:15)) = 65535, i.e. all bits are 1
df$quality <- substring(df$bits, 15, 16)
df$usefulness <- substring(df$bits, 11, 14)
df$land_water <- substring(df$bits, 3, 5)

table(df$quality)
round(table(df$quality) / nrow(df), 3)  # 0.46 "Pixel produced, but most probably cloudy"

table(df$usefulness)  # Zero cases of "0000" i.e. "highest quality"

usefulness_in_pdf <- c("0000",  # Highest quality
                       "0001",
                       "0010",
                       ## 0011 does not appear in table
                       "0100",
                       ## 0101 does not appear in table
                       ## 0110 does not appear in table
                       ## 0111 does not appear in table
                       "1000",
                       "1001",
                       "1010",
                       ## 1011 does not appear in table
                       "1100",  # Lowest quality
                       "1101",  # Quality so low that it is not useful
                       "1110",  # L1B data faulty
                       "1111")  #  Not useful for any other reason/not processed
observed_usefulness <- unique(df$usefulness)
observed_usefulness[!observed_usefulness %in% usefulness_in_pdf]  # NA 0011 0101 0110 0111
mean(!df$usefulness %in% usefulness_in_pdf)  # 0.57
mean(!df$usefulness %in% usefulness_in_pdf & !is.na(df$usefulness))  # 0.47

## Look at land/water mask bits -- should be no "deep ocean" in the middle of Brazil
table(df$land_water)  # Looks reasonable
round(table(df$land_water) / nrow(df), 2)  # .89 land, .01 coastlines, .01 shallow water

land_raster <- raster(extent(qual))
dim(land_raster) <- dim(qual)
land_raster[] <- df$land_water == "001"  # Land (nothing else but land)
png("land_raster.png")
plot(land_raster)
dev.off()
```

For the documentation (which is where I get the usefulness_in_pdf values), see pages 15-16 of http://vip.arizona.edu/documents/MODIS/MODIS_VI_UsersGuide_01_2012.pdf, or https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1 TABLE 2: MOD13Q1 VI Quality.

The values of land / water look correct.  Here's the land raster I generate at the end of the code:

[image: land raster]

The only worrying thing is that I see values of VI usefulness in the data that don't appear in the documentation.  VI usefulness has 4 bits, hence 16 possible values, but the tables in the documentation (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1, click on layers, look at TABLE 2: MOD13Q1 VI Quality) list only 11 values.  Why is that?

**Edit:  I'm on a little-endian machine:**

Following https://serverfault.com/questions/163487/linux-how-to-tell-if-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian, it looks like my machine is little-endian:

```
$ echo -n I | od -to2 | head -n1 | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -c6 
1
```

**Edit:  a specific example in case it's helpful:**

```
> qual[10^6]

2062 
> intToBits(qual[10^6])
 [1] 00 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[26] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> as.integer(intToBits(qual[10^6]))
 [1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> first_k_bits(qual[10^6], k=16, reverse=F)
[1] "0111000000010000"
> sum(2^(0:15) * as.integer(intToBits(qual[10^6]))[1:16])
[1] 2062
```

Comment: I would recommend using [bitwise logical operations](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bitwise.html) to parse MODIS QA bands instead of converting to a string of binary digits. See [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44367/4669) for a detailed walkthrough.

Comment: @dmahr thank you, I'll try that.  Did you suggest it because it's cleaner, or did you notice something incorrect in the code in my original question?  In the qual[10^6] example that I give in my post, which bits are the land / water flag?

Comment: It's cleaner and faster since the computer can keep everything in binary; the downside is that it's harder to debug what's happening under the hood. My R is rusty so I can't speak to your code syntax.

Comment: Adrian. Do you find reason why there is value like "0110"? I also run your code with my data, Could you please tell me how do you solve problem? And is it possible that you share your code with me? Thanks a lot
Chengxiu

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/72054)

Comment: Can we apply this script to MOD09A1 ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79108)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a tiny error, as far as I can see. Your substrings are incorrect. This can be seen by comparing the result from a 'which(df$bits="0000100001000100")' with a number of observed unique values, which can be seen in ArcGIS when colouring the tif-file by unique values. 00001000 01000100 = 2116, and there are 3891233 of that number in both ArcGIS and R. This tells us that everything up to, and including the construction of the data.frame went well.

Next step is where it goes wrong. The problem arises from combining the description of the QA layer and the substring function. The order of the bits are as one would expect, but the numbering in the description reads from right to left, while substring works from left to right.

From your own example: (2062)Base10 = (0000100000001110)Base2 - not (0111000000010000)Base2. You have to reverse it or adapt your mind to reverse the information in the MODIS-QC layer. If you don't reverse it, and adapt your substring, you will have to consider that the structure of the string doesn't match that of the MODIS-QC information. Main thing becomes that the structure of multi-bit flags are reversed.
Easier solution is to reverse and adapt the substring as below:

Go from:

```
df$quality <- substring(df$bits, 1, 2)
df$usefulness <- substring(df$bits, 3, 6)
df$land_water <- substring(df$bits, 12, 14)
```

To:

```
df$quality <- substring(df$bits, 15, 16)
df$usefulness <- substring(df$bits, 11, 14)
df$land_water <- substring(df$bits, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this.  Just to be sure, did you notice the reverse=T flag in my first_k_bits function?

Comment: I tried this suggestion with both reverse=T and reverse=F -- in both cases I saw cases of deep or moderate ocean.

Comment: I used with it reverse=T.

Comment: In that case I get 130,518 cases (around 10% of total) of  df$land_water == "111" i.e. deep ocean.  Do you get the same?

Comment: That said, these are actually all cases where df$bits == "1111111111111111", so I will get "111" in the land / water flag regardless of how I parse it.  Will edit my original post to point this out.

Comment: Mikkel, following your suggestion gives me several values of df$usefulness which don't appear in the MOD13Q1 VI Quality table.  Do you get the same result?  I added an edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Adrian, a full set of 1s is the no-data border of the tile. As such, they are to be expected given the reprojection in MRT.

Comment: Thank you Mikkel, that makes sense.  The land / water values look correct when I remove the no-data border and then use your answer.  There's only one thing I'm not sure about:  I see lots of VI usefulness values in that data (e.g. 0110) that don't appear in the official documentation.  Do you know why that is?  Are they valid values that the documentation just omits for brevity?

Comment: @Adrian, I am uncertain as to why there is a use of undocumented 'usefulness' classifiers, one would imagine that 7 variations upon the theme 'not perfect, but not completely bad' would be enough. I would expect the usage to be based on the principle of 'lower value is better', given the description in the User Guide and the distribution of values in the actual data.

Comment: For future reference: an answer from the LPDAAC concerning the undocumented usefulness values can be found here: [http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193101/21872](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193101/21872)