# Handling MOD13Q1 NDVI Product Quality Assessment (QA) flags?

Tags: remote-sensing, modis

I am working on MOD13Q1 NDVI Product and i want to apply Savitzky Golay filter for smoothing  Ndvi time series  using Quality Assessment(QA)  flags.

I studied MOD13Q1 NDVI help file  and found that possible range of values for quality layer is  (0-65534) .

For applying SG filter in TIMESAT software i need 3 ranges of QA values for assigning weight of relative importance (1, 0.5, and 0.1) to corresponding ndvi values.

Which ranges of QA values will be useful, moderate useful and useless?

Comment: Have you ever worked with the QA bits from MODIS before?

Comment: I am trying to understand about it by converting bits into value, for example for bit 2-5 1100 is equal to 48 value without considering bit 0-1 and 6-15. But i am facing a difficulty how i can define a thresold below which QA flags have good quality for assigning maximum weight to corresponding ndvi values. Similarly define ranges for moderate weight and least weight to qa values.

Comment: Which software are you using for this?

Comment: i want to use Timesat for smoothing NDVI time series. Any how I know  little bit about R language as well.

Comment: You can combine the answer from @Luke with the approach in this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144441/how-can-i-parse-modis-mod13q1-quality-layers-in-r/144487#144487 which relates to working with MODIS QAQC bits in R.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want three ranges - 1, 0.5 and 0, I'd use MOD13Q1 Pixel Reliability instead of VI Quality. From the [MOD13Q1 page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1):

```
TABLE 1: MOD13Q1 Pixel Reliability
Rank Key Summary QA     Description                                            
      -1 Fill/No Data   Not Processed                                          
       0 Good Data      Use with confidence                                    
       1 Marginal data  Useful, but look at other QA information               
       2 Snow/Ice       Target covered with snow/ice                           
       3 Cloudy         Target not visible, covered with cloud
```

Read the 250m 16 days pixel reliability summary QA layer into an array and assign 1 to your relative importance where QA is 0, 0.5 where QA is 1 and 0 where QA is any other value.

I don't know `r` but in python it would be something like:

```
# Assuming the 250m 16 days pixel reliability summary QA layer has been read into "qa" array
importance = numpy.zeros(qa.shape)
importance[qa == 0] = 1
importance[qa == 1] = 0.5
```

If you want to use the usefulness flags, they are stored as 4 bits in a two dimensional unsigned 16 bit integer array:

```
TABLE 2: MOD13Q1 VI Quality
Bit 0 is the least significant (read bit words right to left)

bit Long Name    Value Key                                                                               
0–1 MODLAND_QA      00 VI produced, good quality                                                         
                    01 VI produced, but check other QA                                                   
                    10 Pixel produced, but most probably cloudy                                          
                    11 Pixel not produced due to other reasons than clouds                               
2–5 VI usefulness 0000 Highest quality                                                                   
                  0001 Lower quality                                                                     
                  0010 Decreasing quality                                                                
                  0100 Decreasing quality                                                                
                  1000 Decreasing quality                                                                
                  1001 Decreasing quality                                                                
                  1010 Decreasing quality                                                                
                  1100 Lowest quality                                                                    
                  1101 Quality so low that it is not useful                                              
                  1110 L1B data faulty                                                                   
                  1111 Not useful for any other reason/not processed                                     
<SNIP>...
```

In python you can use the bitwise right shift (>>) and 'and' (&) operators to extract VI usefulness:

```
# Assuming the 250m 16 days VI Quality detailed QA layer has been read into a UInt16 array "qa"
usefulness = (qa >> 2) & 15 # Right shift 2 bits and extract 1st 4 bits (values of 0-15)
importance = numpy.zeros(qa.shape)
importance[usefulness <= 7] = 0.5
importance[usefulness == 0] = 1
```

Note the [TimeSAT documentation](http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/docs/TIMESAT32_software_manual.pdf) states:

> In previous work weights w = 0; 0.5 and 1. have been used for values in the time-series associated with, respectively, cloudy, mixed and clear conditions.  There are, of course, no general rules for converting ancillary data to weights associated with the values in the time-series, and the user of the Timesat program is encouraged to take an experimental approach and test different settings.

So you don't have to confine yourself to three weights and can use the VI Quality to define a range of weights. Again a python example:

```
# Assuming the 250m 16 days VI Quality detailed QA layer has been read into a UInt16 array "qa"
usefulness = (qa >> 2) & 15 # Right shift 2 bits and extract 1st 4 bits (values of 0-15)
importance = numpy.zeros(qa.shape)
importance[usefulness == 0] = 1
importance[usefulness == 1] = 0.8
importance[usefulness == 2] = 0.6
importance[usefulness == 3] = 0.5
importance[usefulness == 4] = 0.4
importance[usefulness == 5] = 0.3
importance[usefulness == 6] = 0.2
importance[usefulness == 7] = 0.1
```