# Parsing MODIS QA layers

Tags: modis, data-quality

I'd like to correctly parse the MOD13Q1 VI Quality layer (see Table 2 in "layers" [here](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1)). For this, I'm trying to follow Example 1 from [this tutorial](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/modis/docs/MODIS_LP_QA_Tutorial-1b.pdf) (page 10).

I'll illustrate my problem with a pixel value of "VI Quality" from my real data set: 35038

First, I transform it to the binary value `1000100011011110`.

Then, I separate this binary value into different bit words (from right to left) according to Table 2:

`1 0 001 0 0 0 11 0111 10`

Following Example 1 ("Please bear in mind that the binary bit-string is parsed from right to left, and the individual bits within a bit-word are read from left to right."), I would then assume that I'd get the following bit words for the different categories:

```
MODLAND_QA: 10
VI usefulness: 0111
Aerosol quantity: 11
... and so on
```

However, the problem is that the value `0111` doesn't exist in Table 2. I guess that there are two possible explanations for this:

1. I made a mistake trying to apply the tutorial.  In that case can you point me to the right direction?
2. I applied the tutorial correctly, but Table 2 is incorrect or incomplete. Could anybody confirm if this might really be the case, and if yes, where to find information about missing values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer from LPDAAC:

> It goes from 0000 to 1111, with 0000 being the best and 1111 worst.
>
> For some reason the table on the product page wasn't complete.
>
> To understand what it means and how it could be used you need to
>   understand how it is constructed. Basically we start by assigning a
>   VI_Usefulness of ZERO (0000) and then decrease it based on the various
>   QA flags (cloud, shadow, cirrus, etc...), and viewing geometry, etc...
>
> So you can add any other bit combination and simply rank it as
>   decreasing QA.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is option 2. As also documented in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144441/how-can-i-parse-modis-mod13q1-quality-layers-in-r/144487#144487) there are undocumented QA-values in the MOD13Q1. I have yet to find a good reason for the lack of documentation, and I expect that you'd have to directly contact the LPDAAC people for a correct answer.

Note that in the other post, the observation can be found in the comments-section.