# MOD09A1 QC layer

Tags: raster, r, modis, data-quality

Does anyone know how to handle MOD09A1 Quality flags (QC) in in R? 
I was trying to use [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package but unable to unlock the QC band.

Answer (score 9):

This is a good question, naturally isn't obvious how to handle this kind of data. For example, the product **State QA** has 16 bits and there are single, double and triple bit flags combinations:

[image]

For example, a bit flag combination as 0-0-0-0-0-0-00-01-001-0-00 means:

- 00 cloud state: clear
- 0 cloud shadow: no
- 001 land/water flag: land
- 01 aerosol quality: low
- 00 cirrus detected: no
- 0 internal cloud algorithm flag: no
- 0 internal fire algorithm flag: no
- 0 MOD35 snow/ice flag: no
- 0 Pixel is adjacent to cloud: no
- 0 BRDF correction performed: no
- 0 internal snow algorithm flag: no

Decoding bit flags like this is really easy, but QA band came in a [image: i10] format, where bit flags are in [image: i2]. So, we need to transform a base 10 number to a base 2 number.

---

## R procedure

I'll use a real example for this purpose:

```
library(raster)

qflags <- raster('~/Downloads/2269893769/MOD09A1_A2017209_h11v11_006_2017218044841_MOD_Grid_500m_Surface_Reflectance_sur_refl_state_500m_deb6f7af.tif')

plot(qflags)
```

[image: plot]

You can convert integers numbers to binary with [`intToBits()` function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144441/how-can-i-parse-modis-mod13q1-quality-layers-in-r?rq=1), but I'll do it from zero creating a function that converts to binary with other options for this purpose:

```
BitFlagDecoder <- function(x,bits=16,obj=15){
  i <- 1
  result <- rep(0,bits)
  if(length(obj)>1){
    ind <- max(obj):min(obj)+1 # bit index
  }else{
     ind <- obj + 1 
    }
  if(is.na(x)){
    result[1:bits] <- NA
  }else{
    while(x > 0){
      result[i]  <- x %% 2
      x <- x %/% 2
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  return(as.numeric(paste(result[ind],collapse = '')))
}
```

Where `bits` is the number of bits of the scene and `obj` is the objective zone or **Bit No.** (see table above). Just calculate new values and add them to a new raster:

```
newValues <- sapply(values(qflags),FUN= BitFlagDecoder)

r <- setValues(qflags,newValues)

plot(r)
```

[image]

Also, you can create dictionaries to plot the raster as categorical:

```
dictionary <-  data.frame(Bit=c(0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111),
                          Class=c('shallow ocean','land',
                                  'ocean coastlines and lake shorelines',
                                  'shallow inland water',
                                  'ephemeral water','deep inland water',
                                  'continental/moderate ocen',
                                  'deep ocean'))

rClass <- as.factor(r)
lvls <- levels(rClass)[[1]]
lvls[['BitFlags']] <- dictionary[match(lvls[,1],dictionary$Bit),'Class']
levels(rClass) <- lvls

library(rasterVis)

levelplot(rClass)
```

[image]

And finally, testing for snow (Bit No. 15, the last bit):

```
BitFlagDecoder <- function(x,bits=16,obj=15){
  i <- 1
  result <- rep(0,bits)
  if(length(obj)>1){
    ind <- max(obj):min(obj)+1 # bit index
  }else{
     ind <- obj + 1 
    }
  if(is.na(x)){
    result[1:bits] <- NA
  }else{
    while(x > 0){
      result[i]  <- x %% 2
      x <- x %/% 2
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
  return(as.numeric(paste(result[ind],collapse = '')))
}

newValues <- sapply(values(qflags),FUN= BitFlagDecoder)

r <- setValues(qflags,newValues)

rClass <- as.factor(r)
lvls <- levels(rClass)[[1]]
lvls[['BitFlags']] <- c('No snow','Snow')
levels(rClass) <- lvls

levelplot(rClass)
```

[image]

---

## Reference RGB image:

[image]