# Averaging MODIS 8-day LST for each pixel in a region to generate annual mean LST

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, modis

I have downloaded 8-day MODIS LST products (MOD11A2) for the whole year of 2011  and is there any method in R to extract those pixels in **clear sky** **conditions** with  **emissivity error < 0.01** and **LST error < 1 K** and average LST values for each pixel to generate only one raster map for 2011? My current code is not complete as below.

```
    lst <- lapply(list.files("D:/LST2011/Surf_Temp_8Days_1Km_v6/LST_Day_1km", 
                     pattern = "LST_Day_1km", full.names = T), raster)
    csd <- lapply(list.files("D:/LST2011/Surf_Temp_8Days_1Km_v6/Days_Clear", 
                     pattern = "Days_Clear", full.names = T), raster)
    mean_lst <- temporalComposite(lst, csd, fun = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You need to translate QA band from [integer to binary](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod11a2). In R, I posted an [answer related to this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/252404/80215). You can extract emiss. error and LST error by 8-days composite and after this apply a mask. Without sample data, I can't help you more

Comment: Does this code actually work or did you just cobble something together for the post? I do not see how your lapply function would work on a stack with a call to raster. Are you creating a list object full of single rasters? You want to read the data as a stack and then use overlay to calculate the mean. This is quite simple and has be covered numerous times on this forum.