# What is the meaning of ' QC_val=0x...' in the cleanMODIS of the bfastSpatial package?

Tags: r, modis, time-series

I am using the bfastSpatial package in R. One of the parameters that I have to set is the QC_val=0x 'a number'.
I do not understand what number I have to insert.
I am using MOD11A2 product (MODIS LST 8-day product).
I have read that QC values to KEEP in the data. But what I can not understand is what are the values. For example, the range of the values in the QC images that I use is [2-90].

Comment: What function in that package needs that parameter? I can't see any mention of QC_val here: http://www.loicdutrieux.net/bfastSpatial/

Comment: The function cleanMODIS. Here is an example:
MODISclean <- cleanMODIS(x=modis, data_SDS=1, QC_SDS=3, bit=TRUE, QC_val=0x19, fill = (32761:32767))

Comment: Have you read the help for that function?  If so, what part of it do you not understand. Please edit your question.

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope that now I have made my problem more clear.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> Numeric or vector of numerics. Quality control values to keep in the
>   data. If bit is set to TRUE QC_val is a BYTE (hexadecimal or decimal)
>   where each bit refers to a bit in the QC layer element (i.e.: bitpos =
>   0xA1 targets bits 7, 5 and 0 --- 1010 0001). When bits targetted by
>   QC_val are activated, the corresponding observation in the data layer
>   is filtered out.

Check product documentation to know which QA flag you need to preserve: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/product_documentation/mod11_user_guide.pdf

If you still don't know how to handle QA Flags, convert QA flags to layers and mask layers after: [MOD09A1 QC layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182924/mod09a1-qc-layer)