# When working with MOD09GA product, is supposed QC bitmask for high aerosol quantity to return 4 values?

Tags: gdal, remote-sensing, modis, filter, data-quality

it's the first time I'm working with MODIS data and I am a bit confused about how bits work and how masks are created. After a bit of research I've been able to understand, more or less, how bit filtering works -- using the help found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44353/mod-35-cloud-mask-hdf-in-envi/44367#44367) and MODIS documentation files ([1](https://atmosphere-imager.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/ModAtmo/QA_Plan_C6_Master_2015_05_05_1.pdf) and [2](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/306/MOD09_User_Guide_V6.pdf)).

I am using MOD09GA product to create cloud and aerosol free mask data. I built my binary filter based on the information found in the next table (file 2, page 24).

[image: State_1km table]

When doing bitwise operations in python and applying the bit filter to the QA band (state_1km), I am not fully sure that what it returns is right, since it generates a mask with 4 integer values (0, 1, 2 and 3) when I was expecting 2 (0 and 1).

I will show this with an example. You can download the .hdf file from [here](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.006/2008.01.01/MOD09GA.A2008001.h10v05.006.2015169041625.hdf), although you'll need you login credentials.

```py
import gdal
import numpy as np

# Opening MODIS hdf file
 modisImage = gdal.Open("data/MOD09GAMOD09GA.A2008001.h10v05.006.2015169041625.hdf") 

# Getting subdatasets
subData = modisImage.GetSubDatasets()
data = {}
for fname, name in subData:
    newname = name.split("] ")[1]
    without_type = newname.split(" (")[0]
    print(without_type)
    data[without_type] = gdal.Open(fname).ReadAsArray()

# =============================================================================
# # num_observations_1km MODIS_Grid_1km_2D
# # state_1km_1 MODIS_Grid_1km_2D    <-- I want this one
# # SensorZenith_1 MODIS_Grid_1km_2D
# # .
# # .
# # .
# # .
# # q_scan_1 MODIS_Grid_500m_2D
# =============================================================================


# now call the desired band
qc = data["state_1km_1 MODIS_Grid_1km_2D"]
```

Cloud state, cloud shadow and land/water bit masks are returning a mask with the values expected (0 and 1), but when I apply the same approach to the aerosol quantity I can't understand the mask returned.

```py
# Aerosol quantity information is in the Bitshift 6 and Bitmask 0-3 (first and third columns of the table). In this case, I want to return only high quantity aerosol

qcAerosol = (qc >> 6) & 3

# Checking values returned (more than 2 values)
np.unique(qcAerosol) # array([  0,  1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)

# Taking a closer look to te values returned
bin(1)  # '0b1'
bin(2) # '0b10'
bin(3) # '0b11'
```

The qcAerosol mask created is the one in the image. As you can see, it has four colors corresponding to each value.

[image: Mask returned for qcAerosol]

Each value returned in the mask, maps a binary value in the table:

- 1 corresponds to the bit mask for 'low aerosol quantity'
- 2 corresponds to the bit mask for 'average aerosol quantity'
- 3 corresponds to the bit mask for 'high aerosol quantity'

Since I want a 'high aerosol quantity' mask, I need a last step to create one.

```py
qcAerosol[qcAerosol != 3] = 0
qcAerosol[qcAerosol == 3] = 1
```

Getting the next mask.

#### Python qcAerosol

[image: Python qcAerosol]

However, as I noted above, bitmasks for cloud state, cloud shadow and land/water only return two values, 0 and 1. I think there could be a problem with my approach, therefore my question is raised: When working with MOD09GA product, is supposed QC bitmask for high aerosol quantity to return 4 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, as I noted above, bitmasks for cloud state, cloud shadow and land/water only return two values, 0 and 1. I think there could be a problem with my approach, therefore my question is raised: When working with MOD09GA product, is supposed QC bitmask for high aerosol quantity to return 4 values?

According to the description of the quality assessment flags, there can be 4 combinations: `'00'`, `'01'`, `'10'` and `'11'`. Thus, it should and it does return 4 values as long as they exist in the QA layer.

#### Details

The quality assessment (binary) flags for MOD09GA Science Data Sets are indeed detailed in [MODIS Surface Reflectance User’s Guide (Collection 6)](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/306/MOD09_User_Guide_V6.pdf). Specifically, the Data product state QA flags are described in Table 13 (the one you copy-pasted in your question).

Breaking down the instruction

```
qcAerosol = (qc >> 6) & 3
```

after the `=` sign in two parts:

1. `qc >> 6` which performs a bitwise right shift of all pixel values in `qc` by 6 positions. To exemplify, let us use the unsigned 16-bit integer 174272. Its binary form is (all code below in Python):

   ```
   bin(174272)[2:]
   '101010100011000000'
   ```

   Shifting this bit-pattern to the right by 6 positions, will result in

   ```
   bin(174272 >> 6)[2:]
   '101010100011'
   ```

   which is the integer

   ```
   int(bin(174272 >> 6)[2:], 2)
   2723
   ```

   which, by the way, is the same as

   ```
   174272 / 2**6
   2723
   ```

   Theory says we *multiply* if we shift to the left!)
2. `& 3` performs a bitwise AND of all shifted `qc` values with `3` which is the integer form for the binary string `'11'`. The 'AND' operation will *compare* the first two bits of each (now shifted) `qc` pixel values with `'11'`.

   Continuing the example with the integer `174272`, the second step is:

   ```
   int(bin(174272 >> 6)[2:], 2) & 3
   3
   ```

   This is expected as we *compare* the first two bits (reading from right to left) `'1010101000`**`11`**`'` with `'11'` which in turn will result to `'11'` which is the binary form of the integer `3`.

   For the sake of completeness, the possible *comparisons* are:

   - `'00'` AND `'11'` results in `'00'` or `0`
   - `'01'` AND `'11'` results in `'01'` or `1`
   - `'10'` AND `'11'` results in `'10'` or `2`
   - `'11'` AND `'11'` results in `'11'` or `3`

   Thus, `np.unique(qcAerosol)` can return **at most** 4 different integer values (`0` or `1` or `2` or `3`). It may, however, return less or only one according to the recorded state of the pixels for bits 7 and 6.

As for the other data quality states,

- "cloud state" is a double bit, thus `2^2 = 4` states can be encoded
- "cloud shadow" is a single bit, thus only `2^1 = 2` states can be encoded (`0` or `1`)
- "land/water" is a triple bit, thus the possible combinations are `2^3 = 8`: `'000'` or `0`, `'001'` or `1`, `'010'` or `2`, `'011'` or `3`, `'100'` or `4`, `'101'` or 5, `'110'` or `6`, `'111'` or `7`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I fully understand it now. Only one thing to add to explain the binary masks I obtained. Since in my use case I wanted to mask land and cloudy situations, I used bitmasks 001 and 01, respectively, which resulted in masks with 0 and 1 values when computing the AND comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with bitpacked mask values in MODIS (like I was), I made a package to deal with them more easily. Details are here https://pypi.org/project/unpackqa/

Code to pull the aerosol quantity from the above MOD09 file is as follows

```
from osgeo import gdal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import unpackqa

# Define how qa/qc flags are from Table 13
mod09ga_spec = {'flag_info':{'cloud_state':[0,1],
                             'cloud_shadow':[2],
                             'land_water_flag':[3,4,5],
                             'aerosol_quantity':[6,7],
                             'cirrus_detected':[8,9],
                             'internal_cloud_algorithm_flag':[10],
                             'internal_fire_algorithm_flag':[11],
                             'MOD35_snow_ice_flag':[12],
                             'pixel_adjacent_to_cloud':[13],
                             'salt_pan':[14]},
                 'max_value' : 65535,
                 'num_bits'  : 16}

# Read directly the "state_1km_1" band. This string is derived from GetSubDatasets() in gdal
qc = gdal.Open('HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD09GA.A2008001.h10v05.006.2015169041625.hdf":MODIS_Grid_1km_2D:state_1km_1').ReadAsArray()

# unpack flags into a dictionary.
flags = unpackqa.unpack_to_dict(qc, product=mod09ga_spec)

unique_values = [0,1,2,3]
plt.imshow(flags['aerosol_quantity'], interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar(ticks=unique_values,values=unique_values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

`unpackqa.unpack_to_dict()` returns a dictionary where keys are the flag names defined in `mod09ga_spec`, and each key value is an array the same shape as the qc raster.

```
flags.keys()
dict_keys(['cloud_state', 'cloud_shadow', 'land_water_flag', 'aerosol_quantity', 'cirrus_detected', 'internal_cloud_algorithm_flag', 'internal_fire_algorithm_flag', 'MOD35_snow_ice_flag', 'pixel_adjacent_to_cloud', 'salt_pan'])

flags['cloud_shadow'].shape
(1200,1200)
```